# How to use rsa library on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I found rsa class(RSACryptoServiceProvider) can be used on C#, but it cannot be used on Windows Phone.

If I have a request on Window Phone 7 to use RSA, how can I do?

Answer (score 3):

You could try http://scrypt.codeplex.com/. Their web page is claiming that they have used it successfully in Windows Phone 7. And it is even compatible with RSACryptoServiceProvider.